# EXTJS4, combobox, multiselect, need VALUE field to highlight ALL returned from DB

Tags: extjs, combobox, extjs4, multi-select

Using EXTJS v4, I want to update the VALUE field of a multi-select combobox i have, with ALL the records returned from my remote query. In my case I want to update the multiselect 'value' field not the 'valueField' entries, and highlight the values in the list that are returned from the database query for the combo list. For the combobox, if you set up the combo to run with a config entry such as this:

displayField: 'TABLENAME',
valueField: 'TABLENAME',
value: ['table1', 'table2', 'table5'],

then when the combo is created if you open the combo you will see these 3 entries as highlighted.

I want to do a remote call, get a list of values returned, and pass them back to the combobox so they appear as highlighted entries in the combobox.

This is what I have so far:

```
[code]
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url     : 'app/store/dbcall/target/GG/table_list_containing_target_svc.php',
    params  : { groupflavor_sn: theGroupFlavor_sn, familyName: familyName },
    method  : 'POST',
    success : function(response, theRecord) {
        var res = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
        var returnedTablesData = res.data;

        // reurned values are either 'blank', or a list of tablenames formatted as JSON.
        // JSON responses will look like this: 
                // {"data":[{"TABLENAME":"TABLE_A1"},{"TABLENAME":"TABLE_A1B"},{"TABLENAME":"TABLE_A5"}]}

        //  combobox object:
        /*
            var msForm = Ext.widget('form', {
                title: 'Tables found for ' + selectedFamily,
                //width: 385,
                height: 150,
                bodyPadding: 10,
                id: 'msForm',
                layout: 'fit',
                items:[{
                    xtype: 'combobox',
                    id: 'myTablesComboId',
                    name: 'myTargets',
                    maxHeight: 150,        
                    width: 210,
                    multiSelect: true,
                    emptyText : "Select targets",
                    store: 'TableComboStore',
                    displayField: 'TABLENAME',
                    valueField: 'TABLENAME',
                    value: ['TABLE_A1', 'TABLE_A10B', 'TABLE_A5'],     //<- this is what will be highlighted in the combo list
                    forceSelection: false,
                    editable: false,
                    queryMode: 'local',
                    ddReorder: true,
                    triggerAction: 'all',
                    listeners: {
                        'click': function() {
                            if (selectedFamily) {  
                                console.log('family selected, and button clicked');
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    listConfig: {          
                        getInnerTpl: function(displayField) {                              
                            return '<tpl for="."><div><img src="' + Ext.BLANK_IMAGE_URL + '" ' + 'class="ux-checkboxlistcombo-icon">{' + (displayField || 'text') + ':htmlEncode}</div></tpl>';
                        }
                    }
                }]
            })      
        */

        // Post value to field
        Ext.getCmp('theTargetLabel').setValue(theGroupFlavor);

        if (res.data === 'blank') {
            console.log("res.data === 'blank'");

            // Entry is found in the database, so clear all values, and ask to resend
            var theTableCombo = Ext.getCmp('myTablesComboId');
            Ext.getCmp('theTargetLabel').setValue(' ');
           theTableCombo.clearValue();
        } 
       else {
            // list of available tables returned as JSON
            // populate list returned into the new table combo, and update with the existing list of tables
            // values returned will be HIGHLIGHTED and the checkbox next to value will be CHECKED in the listing

            var theTableCombo = Ext.getCmp('myTablesComboId');
            var store = theTableCombo.getStore();

            theTableCombo.setValue(returnedTablesData); // this works partially, to return all records found, but they are not highlighted in the combo list
            //theTableCombo.setValue(store.getAt(0).get('TABLENAME')); // this works partially -  record is highlighted in combo list, but only returns the first record
        }

});

[/code]
```

As you can see when we get to the 'else' statement, there is a list of tables I can post back to the combo. But I am getting the list returned, but they are only showing in the combo text field, and the values are not highlighted when I open the combo.

If I use - theTableCombo.setValue(store.getAt(0).get('TABLENAME'));-  I am able to retrieve the first record returned and highlight that record in the combo, but only the first record. I want ALL records returned to show in the combo, as highlighted entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your already working solution to select a single record, wouldn't the following work:

```
var iValues = [];

store.each( function( aRecord ) {
    iValues.push ( aRecord.get('TABLENAME') );
}, this);

theTableCombo.setValue ( iValues );
```

I'm not aware of any better way of doing this (as in without the each).

Comment: By the way, I'm pretty sure it will also work if you do `iValues.push ( aRecord );`

Comment: still having an issue where the record is not highlighting. I am seeing the values in the combo text box, but when I click the button and open the combo, I see no highlighted records that are appearing in the combo text box.

Comment: Your idea about 'each' gave me an idea... what about replacing 'i' for the '0' in this statement:  theTableCombo.setValue(store.getAt(0).get('TABLENAME')); and putting it into a while statement and have the 'i;' populate with store records as long as there are records? I am not sure how to code that, but since the code works to pull in the first record with getAt(0).get('TABLENAME'), if the '0' kept changing to the next records as long as there are records in the store, maybe that would highlight the entries in the combo?

Comment: Something like this:                 store.each( function( aRecord ) {
                                for (i = 0; i < aRecord.length; i++) {
                                    var post = store.getAt(i).get('TABLENAME');
                                    theTableCombo.setValue( post );
                                }                                                              
                            }, this);

Comment: working code:




    var store = theTableCombo.getStore(); 
    var iValues = [];                                                        
    for (i = 0; i < returnedTablesData.length; i++) {
        var post = store.getAt(i).get('TABLENAME');
        console.log('posted record: ', post);
        iValues.push ( post );                                 
    }
    theTableCombo.setValue( iValues );

Comment: Thanks Izhaki. Without your idea of looping through the values with 'each', I would never have figured out using the for loop and pushing values into the array stack.